# Errors while linking Cuda application on MacOS X Mavericks

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cuda, clang

I am trying to build C++ \ Cuda application on MacOS X Mavericks with XCode 5.1.1 and Cuda Toolkit 6.

I am receiving following errors during linking:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in bmp-read.cu.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init in encoder_nostream.cu.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init in encoder_stream.cu.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init in tier1.cu.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in bmp-read.cu.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init in encoder_nostream.cu.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init in encoder_stream.cu.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init in tier1.cu.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tried to use libstdc++ (-lstdc++) option where possible, but with no luck.

Here is part of makefile:

```
# Compilers 
NVCC       := $(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/bin/nvcc
CXX        := g++
CC         := gcc
LINK       := g++ -fPIC

# Includes
INCLUDES  += -I. -I$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/include -I$(COMMONDIR)/inc

# architecture flag for cubin build
CUBIN_ARCH_FLAG := -m32

# Warning flags
CXXWARN_FLAGS := \
    -W -Wall \
    -Wimplicit \
    -Wswitch \
    -Wformat \
    -Wchar-subscripts \
    -Wparentheses \
    -Wmultichar \
    -Wtrigraphs \
    -Wpointer-arith \
    -Wcast-align \
    -Wreturn-type \
    -Wno-unused-function \
    $(SPACE)

CWARN_FLAGS := $(CXXWARN_FLAGS) \
    -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wmissing-prototypes \
    -Wmissing-declarations \
    -Wnested-externs \
    -Wmain \

# Compiler-specific flags
NVCCFLAGS := -ccbin /usr/bin/clang -arch=sm_30 --compiler-options -Wall,-ansi,-Wno-extra-tokens -Xcompiler -stdlib=libstdc++
CXXFLAGS  := $(CXXWARN_FLAGS) -stdlib=libstdc++
CFLAGS    := $(CWARN_FLAGS) -stdlib=libstdc++

...

LIB       := -L$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/lib -L$(LIBDIR) -L$(COMMONDIR)/lib/$(OSLOWER) 
LIB += -lstdc++$(LIBSUFFIX)
```

Comment: I see this in your cmake file : `CUBIN_ARCH_FLAG := -m32`. However it seems that your machine is a 64bits

Comment: I think you should use `-m64` But that might not be the only problem. My experience in C++ is very limited

Comment: Just tried this flag, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick was in passing -stdlib=libstdc++ to the linker.

`LINK := g++ -fPIC -stdlib=libstdc++`

Comment: @ nemezis Yep! well done! However I am just wondering what happens when you give the linker this flag while keeping -m32. Does it work?